# layout for multiple DPI and SIZE screens in android

Tags: android

how am i refer a layout in res library for differnt screens (DPI and SIZE)?

can i do this in re folder:

```
layout-mdpi-xlarge
layout-mdpi-normal
layout-xhdpi-large
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

You can find an answer to your question by going through the link in detail.

See the  topic under **Using configuration qualifiers** especially the section under table1.

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation
```

For drawables.

```
 res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
 res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
 res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```